# Serial.Available not working on Arduino nano

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I have a serial application that runs from a nano into a current loop driver.
Now if I connect the Tx straight to the Rx the led is set to HIGH but if I link the Tx/Rx to the current loop board the LED isnt set at all. I have even added a serial to usb monitor to confirm that the current loop board is returning the same hex as is being passed. Any suggestions?

```js
int timeout = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(4800,SERIAL_8E1);
//Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //delay(10000);
  byte inByte1 = 0xF1;
  byte inByte2 = 0x10;
  byte inByte3 = 0xB0;
  
  
//if(timeout == 0)
//{
  Serial.write(inByte1);
  Serial.write(inByte2);
  Serial.write(inByte3);
//}
//timeout = timeout+1;

//if(timeout == 50)
//{
//  timeout=0;
//}
  
//delay(80);

byte inByte4 = 0xE1;
//Serial.println(Serial.available());
 while (!Serial.available()) {
  //timeout =0;
    //byte inChar = Serial.read();
    //Serial.println(inChar);
//digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //if(inChar == inByte4)
    //{
    //   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //}
     Serial.write(inByte1);
  Serial.write(inByte2);
  Serial.write(inByte3);
  delay(80);
  }

while (Serial.available()) {
  //timeout =0;
    //byte inChar = Serial.read();
    //Serial.println(inChar);
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //if(inChar == inByte4)
    //{
    //   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //}
    
  }
}



String ReadResult(Stream &serial)
{
  int serialState = 0;
  String content = "";
  char character;
  long interval = 10000; 
 //unsigned int timeout = 0;
 unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
 long previousMillis = millis();

 while ( !serial.available() && serialState != 1) {
  currentMillis = millis();
   if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval){
        serialState = 1;
   }
 }
 
 //timeout = 0;

  //while (serial.available()) {
  //  character = serial.read();
  //  content += character;
  //}

  return content;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver that I was feeding to was not returning thecorrect voltage